# js regex to test/find an invalid css classname (that begins with numbers)

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm trying to find a solution to get invalid css class names.
I have:

```
if (/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+/.test(classname)) {}
```

It works fine except that it is not "true" when the name begins with a number, which isn't allowed in css classes. So I tried a lot of things, like:

```
/[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+/
```

It doesn't work … any ideas?
thx!

Comment: `if(/^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_-]*/.test(classname)) { }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the underlying assumption is that a valid class name contains only letters, digits, hyphens or underscores but can't start with a number then you can use a regex like this for valid names:

```
/^[a-z_-][a-z\d_-]*$/i
```

That is, any letter or an underscore or hyphen at the beginning of the string, followed by zero or more of any letter, digit, underscore or hyphen through to the end of the string.

Which, if you want to test for invalid you'd use as:

```
if (!/^[a-z_-][a-z\d_-]*$/i.test(classname)) {
   // invalid, do something
}
```

But although I believe that implements what you've described I don't think class names are supposed to start with a hyphen followed by a digit. So perhaps:

```
if (!/^([a-z_]|-[a-z_-])[a-z\d_-]*$/i.test(classname)) {
   // invalid, do something
}
```

Note that it is easier to make the regex case insensitive via the `i` flag then to use `a-zA-Z`.